# How do you do partial decoding in Netty?

Tags: netty

I am writing a Netty client to talk to am embedded device.  I have looked at the tutorials, but am not sure if my design will work properly in Netty.
Is it possible for a ByteToMessage decoder to decode only part of the message and allow an upstream handler to decode the rest?  If so, how do you communicate upstream to pass the message and the buffer? Or is there a different mechanism?

The protocol I am implementing has the following fields:

1. 16 bit sequence number
2. 8 bit message type
3. 8 bit reserved for future use field
4. Optional - potentially empty and potentially AES encrypted (depending on #2) length message data field that varies in length.

I would like to break down the processing of this into different handlers to reduce the complexity in each handler.

My initial design was to used a FixedLengthFrameDecoder of size 4 and then a ByteToMessageDecoder to convert the sequence number, and message type to an object and skip 1 byte for the reserved field.

Here is where I get stuck.
I want to pass that message onto the next handler, and depending on the message type I want it to continue to read from the bytebuffer to process the optional message part.  Is that something you can do or does every byte need to flow through the entire chain?

I could potentially switch to a ReplayingDecoder and try to do it all in one decoder, but that is going to be a fairly big decoder which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You can send a bytebuf up the pipeline, just like you can with normal objects, and by making a separate view of the original buffer with  `retainedSlice`, or a full copy with `readBytes`